# Understanding UndefinedMetricWarning in classification report with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I have a text classification task with 5 categories the problem is that I am getting bad precision and this warning, probably as a result from unbalaced data(Im not sure):

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py:1771: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.

I guess this warning was produced since the data is clustered in the 5 label. How can I fix this warning and how can I increase the results of the classification report? I also tried a Grid search with the following hyper-parameters:

```
Best parameters set:
    clf__C: 0.1
    vect__max_df: 0.25
    vect__ngram_range: (1, 1)
    vect__use_idf: True

Accuracy:
0.456923076923
```

But still getting bad results, could anybody help me to increase this results with SVC or another model?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have unbalanced data. Half of the data is in one class and there are 3 classes.

Comment: The warning is raised by the classification_report, not the grid search.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know that this was caused by the classification_report, I look at the web in order to fix this and I read [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/robertlayton/authorship_tutorials/blob/master/pyconau2014/PyCon%20AU%202014%20--%20Text%20mining%20online%20data%20with%20scikit-learn.ipynb), as I understood the previous reference fix this issue by using other parameters to do the gridsearch do you think this is due the unbalanced data. Probably this is happening because I have  1190 instances of 2599 in one class. Any idea of how to fix the previous warning?.

Comment: Well then you are not asking about the warning but how to get better results on your data. I wouldn't use an 'rbf' kernel here, and if you do, you have to also search 'gamma'. For the linear kernel, use a wider range of C, and maybe use ``scoring="auc"``. You can also try ``class_weight='auto'``.

Comment: I edited the warning issue, thanks. What about using PCA or another algorithm for increase this results?. Do you think this should work?.

Comment: Maybe because If I reduce the dimension of the data the algorithm will behave better?...

Comment: The dimensionality reduction can not use any information from the label data, while the supervised algorithm can. Unless you know specific things about the noise in the data, unsupervised dimensionality reduction is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipeline and then also grid-search the parameters of the TfidifVectorizer together with the C of the SVC, like n-gram range (1, 1), (1, 2) or (2, 2), maybe set a different max_df, compare against CountVectorizer, maybe try character n-grams (with a higher n-gram range), too.

Comment: I all ready tried that but still dont increase the metrics, I also do a grid search and still the same. thanks for the help.